# VUE frontend + WEBPACK. Boolean expressions give error. Boolean.valueof() work fine

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I just can't understand what the matter is. Boolean expression doesn't work!

```
const { draggingNode, dropType, dropNode } = this.dragState; //dragState is VUE data

console.log('dragState typeof=%o, dragState.draggingNode=%o, dragState.dropNode=%o', typeof dragState, dragState.draggingNode, dragState.dropNode);

console.log('dragState=%o', dragState);

var b = (draggingNode != null && dropNode != null )
console.log('typeof b=%o, instanceof Boolean=%o, b.constructor.name=%o', typeof b, b instanceof Boolean, b.constructor.name);

console.log('draggingNode=%o dropNode=%o b=%o', typeof draggingNode , typeof dropNode, typeof b);
console.log('draggingNode=%o dropNode=%o', draggingNode , dropNode);
console.log('b=%o b.valueOf=%o', b, b.valueOf());
if (b) {
    console.log('b1=true');
} else {
    console.log('b1=false');
}
console.log('b2=', b ? "true" : "false");
console.log('b3=', b.valueOf() ? "true" : "false");
```

console log output:

```
dragState typeof="object", dragState.draggingNode=VueComponent {_uid: 843, _isVue: true, $options: {…}, _renderProxy: Proxy, _self: VueComponent, …}, dragState.dropNode=VueComponent {_uid: 826, _isVue: true, $options: {…}, _renderProxy: Proxy, _self: VueComponent, …}

dragState=
  draggingNode: null
  dropNode: null
  get draggingNode: ƒ reactiveGetter()
  set draggingNode: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
  get dropNode: ƒ reactiveGetter()
  set dropNode: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
 __proto__: Object

typeof b="boolean", instanceof Boolean=false, b.constructor.name="Boolean"
draggingNode="object" dropNode="object" b="boolean"
draggingNode=VueComponent {_uid: 776, _isVue: true, $options: {…}, _renderProxy: Proxy, _self: VueComponent, …} dropNode=VueComponent {_uid: 767, _isVue: true, $options: {…}, _renderProxy: Proxy, _self: VueComponent, …}
b=true b.valueOf=true
b1=false
b2= false
b3= true
```

but if i replace

```
const { draggingNode, dropType, dropNode } = this.dragState; //dragState is
```

to

```
const draggingNode = dragState.draggingNode;
const dropNode = dragState.dropNode;
const dropType = dragState.dropType;
```

All work fine!

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Why `console.log` and `if` give different results for boolean?

Comment: Place a breakpoint on `var b = ....` and check what exactly is the type of "b" (e.g. `typeof` or `instanceof` or `b.constructor.name`)

Comment: Yeah, just try logging the entire object, maybe they're not really booleans. `console.log( this.dragState );`

Comment: I added the information you requested to the original question. As far as I understand, the problem is that dragState.draggingNode and dragState.dropNode have getters. But why did Boolean go crazy?

Comment: Can you try this: `var b = draggingNode && dropNode` and see if it makes a difference? Conditional checks for `null` with just double equals operator is always tricky in my opinion. or use `===`

Comment: b = draggingNode && dropNode give the same result. All adventures began with this expression.

Comment: `===`  solve the problem. But why? And why does the standard way `var b = draggingNode && dropNode` not work?

Comment: Why `console.log` and `if` give different results for boolean?